# How to return two different presentation controllers for two different controllers from extension of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

This is my **extension**:

```
extension UIViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func presentAssignBookToClassesViewController(controller: BWAssignBookToClassesViewController) {

        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
        controller.transitioningDelegate = self
        controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 575)

        presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func presentSettingsStoryboard() {

        if let settingsController = UIStoryboard(name: "TeacherSettingsStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() {

            settingsController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
            settingsController.transitioningDelegate = self
            settingsController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 575)

            presentViewController(settingsController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

    public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

        return BWOverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }
}
```

Within `presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:` I need to return either `BWOverlayPresentationController` or `BWSettingsPresentationController` depending on what method was called. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply distinguish them via `restorationIdentifier` (you can set this simply using **storyboard**):

```
//MARK: - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

    if presented.restorationIdentifier == BWSettingsRestorationIdentifier {
        return BWSettingsPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    } else {
        return BWOverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController?, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {

    // You can create some property in presented/presenting viewController.
    // and check here to return specific viewContoller.

    if (presented.(somePropertyInViewController)) {
        return BWOverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }
    else {
        return BWSettingsPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }
}
```

Comment: But can I do this somehow globally? because my methods are within extension, not directly in UIViewController.

Comment: I would suggest you can create one BaseViewContoller  with two viewController objects  eg: BWOverlayPresentationController, BWSettingsPresentationController and based on condition you can return the the specific view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you can create one BaseViewContoller  with two viewController objects  eg: BWOverlayPresentationController, BWSettingsPresentationController and based on condition you can return the the specific view controller.

```
public func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController?, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
let viewController = BaseViewController()
if (viewController.(somePropertyInViewController)) {
    return BWOverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
else {
    return BWSettingsPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
```